# No refresh on chrome

Tags: google-chrome, web, refresh

I have a problem on chrome, it doesn't refresh my website.

I've changed a picture on my website and when i refresh my website, no changes appeared...

I try to quit chrome and reboot but nothing change.

Comment: this only happens with Chrome? If you use another browser from the same PC, it gets the new picture?

Comment: on Opera anf Firefox it's refreshed well :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to clear the cache and refresh your page again.

1. Click the Chrome menu  on the browser toolbar.
2. Select Tools.
3. Select Clear browsing data.
4. In the dialogue that appears, select the tickboxes for the types of information that you want to remove.
5. Use the menu at the top to select the amount of data that you want to delete. Select beginning of time to delete everything.
6. Click Clear browsing data.

Source: http://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en-GB&answer=95582

Comment: yep i already do it but no changes :/ i select since the beginnig to clear the cache but no changes :/ i'm at the university of techno, i'll try to ask the professors :P